# How would I autoinstall 22.04 from USB?

Tags: system-installation, preseed, cloud-init, ansible, subiquity

What the best way using Subquitity/Seed/Cloudinit to auto install an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 image?

Our staff use Ubuntu and rather than keeping one fat image lying about which is time consuming to update I would rather use files to auto install and then setup our configuration and the default packages we require.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Previously I used the Cubic software to create a custom ISO with a pre-seeding file attached, but it looks like this has been deprecated, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1108327/457077). [Here's the guide on cloud-init which replaces it.](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall). If you need to boot from USB then Cubic might be still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop during the 22.04 cycle used two different installers.

- 22.04 Desktop = Ubiquity installer = [Debian Preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed)
- 22.04 Server = Subiquity installer = Cloud-init

The developers intend to migrate Desktop to Subiquity in a future release of Ubuntu.